# Access name attribute from HTML form with PHP

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Using PHP CodeIgniter, I have a form with multiple numeric inputs, each with a unique name:

```
<td><input type="number" style= 'width: 40px' name="order<?php echo $bannerId?>" value="<?php echo $banner->b_order; ?>"</td>
```

I can access the field value using:

```
$_POST['order'];
```

but is there a way in PHP to access the name attribute itself, instead of the value?

So in the controller I can use the $bannerId variable echoed in the form.

Comment: if you display the keys of $_POST ? array_keys()  http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-keys.php

Comment: `$this->input->post[ 'banner_id' ];`

Comment: @Blinkydamo => unique names seem dynamicly set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using array keys you could get all the 'names' and then loop over them:

```
array_keys($_POST)
```